# How to get li data attribute inside iframe using jaavascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I want to get data attribute of li element from iframe. iframe contains link of another domain. so please help me. Any answer?

Answer (score 0):

write something like this :

```
$('li:contains("Test3")').data()  //*Replace Test3 with your text lies in li*
```